# Container for multiple typedef of boost::function

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I have a multiple amount of

> boost:function

type defined members:

```
typedef boost::function<void(PARAM_LIST1)> Func1;
typedef boost::function<void(PARAM_LIST2)> Func2;
typedef boost::function<void(PARAM_LIST3)> Func3;
...//and more

Func1 f1;
Func2 f2;
Func3 f3;
...//and more
```

I would like to store f1, f2, f3,... in a container.
Particularly, for passing all f's as one parameter.

What is the best conteiner for that and what type should I use for the template?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the functions are different types, and have no common interface that would allow use of a base class (smart) pointer, they cannot be stored in a `std::vector` or other `std` container.

A possible solution is to use a [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html), or a user-defined container `class`, to store the different function types which can then be passed to a function as a single parameter. However, this restricts the number of instances of each function type to one (unless a container per function type is used to store the function instances). See online [tuple demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=da0eefd7a76d50e7d1f64c3f78257e88-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Answer (score 1):

As @hmjd says, you could use `boost::tuples`, but if you want to have more freedom on the number and the types of functions you are storing, you should use a normal container (`std::vector`, for example) in conjunction with [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html).

It goes like:

```
typedef boost::function<void(PARAM_LIST1)> Func1;
typedef boost::function<void(PARAM_LIST2)> Func2;
typedef boost::function<void(PARAM_LIST3)> Func3;
...

std::vector< boost::any > functions;

functions.push_back(Func1(actualFunc1));
functions.push_back(Func2(actualFunc2));
functions.push_back(Func3(actualFunc3));
...
```

and it's used casting the exact type for each function:

```
Func1 & f1 = boost::any_cast< Func1 >(functions[0]);
f1(...) //actual usage
Func2 & f2 = boost::any_cast< Func2 >(functions[1]);
f1(...) //actual usage
```

or even directly:

```
boost::any_cast< Func3 >(functions[2])(...) //actual usage
```